# Observer Pattern for JTextField?

Tags: java, observer-pattern, jtextfield

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Boy
{
      int age = 25;
}
```

I have a JTextField, age, that updates the 'age' instance field of Boy.  Alternatively, if the age of the boy is changed another way (perhaps, setAge() ), I need to be able to reflect this change in the JTextField.

Using the observer pattern is one way.  In this case, am I forced to create a new class JTextFieldThatObserves (which inherits from JTextField and implements Observer)

Is the default JTextField incapable of doing what I need it to do?

Comment: You're not *forced* to create a JTextFieldThatObserves.  You could just create an observer that calls setText() on your plain ol' JTextField.  Favor delegation over inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not ship with an automatic *binding framework* for Swing components and an object's fields. This is one of its major flaws!

I'm afraid the only mechanism to do this is to use the observer pattern on both the widget and the object and *watchful of infinite cycles*.

One thing useful in these cases is a `PropertyEditor` as it saves you from creating a gazillion different listener/event classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing more than a trivial amount of this sort of thing, I strongly suggest that you invest a little time learning one of the binding frameworks available for Java.  I personally use [Better Beans Bindings](http://kenai.com/projects/betterbeansbinding/pages/Home).